# invalid salt error message when trying to read back and compare from database

Tags: python, tkinter, encoding, passwords, bcrypt

Hi I am trying to make a simple login in system and having problems with hashing the password and comparing it with the users input using bcrypt using tkinter in python 3. I think I have encoded/decoded them properly but now i am getting the error message "invalid salt", any suggestions?

error code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Kev/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/Login/login.py", line 296, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: [sign_in(), root.withdraw()])
  File "C:/Users/Kev/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/Login/login.py", line 33, in sign_in
    if sign_in_verification():
  File "C:/Users/Kev/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/Login/login.py", line 54, in sign_in_verification
    if bcrypt.checkpw(pw, pw_to_check):
  File "C:\Users\Kev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 107, in checkpw
    ret = hashpw(password, hashed_password)
  File "C:\Users\Kev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 86, in hashpw
    raise ValueError("Invalid salt")
ValueError: Invalid salt



password = tk.StringVar()
raw_password = r"{}".format(password)    # convert tkinter string variable to raw string
hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(raw_password.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt())  # generate hashed pw
```

---

```
def add_account():
    new_password_info = hashed_password.decode("utf-8")
    new_username_info = username.get()

    file = open(file_name, "a")
    file.write(new_username_info + "." + new_password_info ")
    file.close()
```

---

```
def sign_in_verification():  
    pw = password.get().encode("utf-8")    # encode password

    if username.get() == "" or pw == "":
        return False
    else:
        for line in open(file_name, "r").readlines():
            login_info = line.strip().split(".")
            if username.get() == login_info[0]:

                pw_to_check = login_info[1].encode("utf-8")    # 

                # check passwords match
                if bcrypt.checkpw(pw, pw_to_check):
                    return True
```

Comment: Post an example of the string that is stored in the database. Then post an example of the string that your code retrieved from the database. See if they a) are valid b) match